# What disease prevents donating bone marrow?

Tags: science-based, diseases, transplant

In my story character signed agreement by which he had to donate bone marrow to person in need of it in exchange of money. Right after signing agreement, character received money (lets say its enough to buy one bedroom flat), and decided to waste time, until his recipient dies. Probably, best is to receive any disease that:

1. lasts 1-2 years, making bone marrow unusable for transplant (or it can be prolonged to 1-2 years)
2. is not very fatal and do not cripple character too much
3. it seems like possible one to catch naturally, so recipients lawyers cannot sue my character

My character is healthy male in late teens years, he is quite smart, he lives in East European rural disrict with a lot of forests, crop fields, etc. Story happens around 2000 year, so there is dialup internet and public libraries present. Of course, no magic present.
Ideally, this should be disease, you can catch by drinking contaminated water from spring deep in woods.

So, question: what disease is not dangerous, but makes bone marrow transplant dangerous to recipients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tuberculosis.**

[Donor derived Mycobacterium tuberculosis infection after solid‐organ transplantation: A comprehensive review](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/tid.12971)*

A healthy young man can usually handle tuberculosis for a long time.  It is still endemic in Eastern Europe.  But the combination of tuberculosis and the immune suppressing medicines necessary after bone marrow transplant is a death sentence.  Suppressing the immune system in the context of TB lets the TB run rampant which is why AIDS and TB is such a deadly combination.

Your guy can go get TB from a prostitute known to have it.  She is happy for the business.  When he is found to have it (because donor is going to know) the state might try to make him take his medicine.  But there is drug resistant tuberculosis too.

I am curious why your character is such a jerk; donating the marrow does not do him any harm except for a little discomfort.  But it looks like you already have me interested in your story!

*No marrow transplants in this series but the principle is sound.